# Can we hold 2 data types in a STL list?

Tags: c++, list, stl

i want my list to hold an integer value as well as a string value. is this possible?
I am implementing a hash table using STL lists which can store only the integer. I am hashing a string to get the index where i am storing my integer. Now i want my string to be stored with the integer as well.

EDIT 1:
so i am using this statement:

```
    list<pair<int,string>> table[127];
```

and here is the error im getting:
`>>' should be`> >' within a nested template argument list
ok i fixed this.. it seems i didn't put a space in the ">>" so now its fix

next question
how do i add my pair to the table array?

Comment: std::pair<int, std::string> ?

Comment: Or why not just use std::map or std::unordered_map?

Comment: You're not clear about what you mean with "as well as", that's why you're getting two different answers.  If you mean that each element will contain a string **and** an integer, then you need a `pair`.  If it will be a string **or** an integer, then you need a `struct`-`union` combination.

Comment: it may not be the best practice, but you could store each item as string and convert it when needed.

Comment: Sorry about that.. I mean that i want to store a string and an integer in my list.
I didn't use map or unordered map because i'm really new to this and this is my first attempt and using an array of lists was giving me more of a feel as to what and how things are working in my program thats why.
I'll try using pairs and let you all know if i face any problems thanks a lot! :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have a list of [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair)s or, with c++11, [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple), for example:

```
std::list < std::pair< int, std::string > >list;
std::list < std::tuple< int, std::string > >list;
```

To access the elements inside a pair, use `pair.first` and `pair.second`. To access the elements inside a tuple, use [`std::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get):

```
auto t = std::make_tuple(1,"something");
std::get<0>(t);//will get the first element of the tuple
```

Comment: Thanks this was very helpful.. ill do the changes and let you know if i face any problems

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::pair` or `std::tuple`,

```
std::list<std::pair<int, string>> list;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the string and the integer in a structure and store the objects of the structure.

Each list element can look like:

```
struct element  {
    string str;
    int val;
};
```

This is the C way to handle, please @SingerOfTheFall's answer also.

Comment: Putting `std::string` (or any non-POD type) in a `union` is a bad idea unless you know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Why a `union`? That does not satisfy the requirement of storing both the `int` and `string` together. You can still use a `struct` to hold them, just get rid of the `union`.

Comment: This is not the C version of @SingerOfTheFall's answer.  This is a **disjoint union**: only one of the two will be present and you'll know which one.  SingerOfTheFall suggests a **product**: both will be present.

Comment: I misinterpreted the question. I thought one of them is required. Sorry for that. Updated the answer, please provide feedback (?)